# Using the right code for loading UIView to SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

My goal is using a UIView in SwiftUI and I want have a red View 100X100 in center there for I used this down code for that and it is working:

```
    struct CustomUIViewController2: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CustomUIViewController2>) -> CustomUIViewControllerModel {
        
        return CustomUIViewControllerModel()
        
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: CustomUIViewControllerModel, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CustomUIViewController2>) { }

    class CustomUIViewControllerModel: UIViewController {

        var customUIView = UIView()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            
            super.viewDidLoad()
            
            customUIView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            
            view.addSubview(customUIView)
            customUIView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            customUIView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
            customUIView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
            customUIView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            customUIView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            
        }
  
    }
  
}
```

But after using that code I noticed that I should use loadView instead of viewDidLoad then I started to refactor the up code to down code, I did it, but now the result is deferent from what I wanted! I wanted a red View 100X100 in center as you can see in the down code I tried to make it center but it does not worked, I was wandering what is wrong with this down code to getting a red View 100X100 in center!

```
    struct CustomUIViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CustomUIViewController>) -> CustomUIViewControllerModel {

        return CustomUIViewControllerModel()

    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: CustomUIViewControllerModel, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CustomUIViewController>) {

    }

    class CustomUIViewControllerModel: UIViewController {
        // Use loadView instead of viewDidLoad
        
        override func loadView() {

            view = UIView()
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
            view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
            view.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            view.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

        }
        

    }
}
```

---

use case:

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        CustomUIViewController()
            .background(Color.blue)
        
        CustomUIViewController2()
            .background(Color.blue)
        
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `loadView` like that, on the first line, you're setting the `view` for the `UIViewController`. So, when you set the width and height to 100, that's applying to the entire `view`.

To fix that, you can create your `view` on the first line as you currently have it, then add a subview for the box.

```
struct CustomUIViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CustomUIViewController>) -> CustomUIViewControllerModel {
        
        return CustomUIViewControllerModel()
        
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: CustomUIViewControllerModel, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CustomUIViewController>) {
        
    }
    
    class CustomUIViewControllerModel: UIViewController {
        // Use loadView instead of viewDidLoad
        
        override func loadView() {
            view = UIView()
            
            let boxView = UIView()
            view.addSubview(boxView)
            boxView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            boxView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            boxView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
            boxView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
            boxView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            boxView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        }
        
    }
}
```